# .searchFiles() iterator returns "invalid argument: q" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that takes the name of a file from a spreadsheet, searches my drive for that file, and returns the Id of that file.

I think it doesn't like my query string, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
function SearchDriveFiles (){

var moduleName = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet.getRange("F19").getValue();
var searchFor = 'title contains"'+moduleName+'"'; 

 var names =[];
 var fileIds=[];
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);

 //iterates through files 
while (files.hasNext()) { //This is where the error happens
var file = files.next();
var fileId = file.getId();
fileIds.push(fileId);
var name = file.getName();
names.push(name);}

Logger.log(fileIds);
Logger.log(names);

}
```

I want to log the file name and Id, but every time I run the function I get "Invalid argument: q"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
var searchFor = 'title contains"'+moduleName+'"';
```

#### To:

```
var searchFor = 'title contains "'+moduleName+'"';
```

- Please insert a space.

#### References:

- [Search for files and folders for Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files)

  - When DriveApp is used, Drive API v2 is used. So the filename uses as `title`.
- [Search for Files for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

  - In this document, you can see the explanation about `contains`.

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Oh my gosh that actually worked! I added the space and the function logged the correct file Id and name. Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay I think I accepted it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ian Propst-Campbell Thank you for your response.

Comment: In my case it was all about the lack of those '' chars around filename. I was trying:  `title = ${folderName}`  instead of:  `title = '${folderName}'`